# Solve functional equation $F(s \cdot t)=\int_a^b G(x,t) G(x,s) dx$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations

I need to describe all functions $G(x,y)$ that have following  property:

for some $a,b$ the integral
$$
\int_a^b  G(x,t) G(x,s) dx
$$
is known  function $F$  of one variable $s \cdot t$, i.e.
\begin{gather}
F(s \cdot t)=\int_a^b  G(x,t) G(x,s) dx. \qquad (1)
\end{gather}

The function $G$ is good function,for example it can be expanded in power series in two variables.
The limits  $a,b$ and the function $F$   are known.

My attempt. Differentiate $(1)$ by $t$ and $s:$

\begin{gather*}
F'(st) s=\int_a^b  \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} G(x,s) dx,\\
F'(st) t=\int_a^b  G(x,t) \frac{\partial G(x,s)}{\partial s}  dx.
\end{gather*}

Then

\begin{gather*}
F'(st) s t =\int_a^b  t \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} G(x,s) w(x) dx,\\
F'(st) t s=\int_a^b  s G(x,t) \frac{\partial G(x,s)}{\partial s} w(x) dx,
\end{gather*}

or
$$
\int_a^b \left(  t \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} G(x,s) - s G(x,t) \frac{\partial G(x,s)}{\partial s}\right) dx=0.
$$

Can I conclude now that
$$
 t \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} G(x,s) - s G(x,t) \frac{\partial G(x,s)}{\partial s}=0?
$$

If not, the how to describe all such function $G(x,y)?$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G(x,t)>0$ and $a,b>0$. From
$$ t \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} G(x,s) - s G(x,t) \frac{\partial G(x,s)}{\partial s}=0 $$
one has
$$ \frac{t}{G(x,t)} \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{s}{G(x,s)} \frac{\partial G(x,s)}{\partial t} $$
which holds for arbitrary $s,t\in[a,b]$. So
$$ \frac{t}{G(x,t)} \frac{\partial G(x,t)}{\partial t} \equiv f(x) $$
is independent of $t$. This gives
$$ \frac{\partial \ln G(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{f(x)}{t}. $$
So
$$ \ln G(x,t)-\ln G(x,a)=f(x)(\ln t-\ln a)$$
or
$$ G(x,t)=G(x,a)\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^{f(x)}. $$